# maven and spring mvc is not working?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven

I'm trying to build an application using `Spring MVC` and `Maven 3.0` within `Eclipse` using the webapp. I'm  not able to get to the initial page, or navigate to any other pages from there w/out getting a `404 error`. Please let me know if there's something I'm missing. Thanks!

mvc-dispatcher.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="se.guards.controller" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />


<!-- show pictures -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- also add the following beans to get rid of some exceptions -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

userController.java

```
    package se.guards.controller;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import se.datalayer.guards.service.UserService;
    import se.guard.User;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public class UserController
    {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAllUsers(Model model){

    Collection<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>();

    model.addAttribute("users", userList);
    return "showallusers";

        }

       }
```

showallusers.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 /loose.dtd">
  <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>found users</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <c:forEach var="allusers" items="${users}">
        <tr>
            <td>${allusers.firstname}</td>

            <td>${allusers.lastname}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
        </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer to the questions:

This is the code I'm using. 
The @Controller annotation must be there. 
As I said before I get :
 HTTP Status 404 - /guard_weblayer/ type Status report message /guard_weblayer/ 
description The requested resource (/guard_weblayer/) is not available. 
Apache Tomcat/7.0.25

---

I use a restfule design, a domainlayer, datalayer and weblayer. Can it effecting the weblayer?

Comment: Your web.xml has an extra > in `<servlet-name>>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>`. Please make sure this is the same code you're using in your IDE! If it is, correct that and try again, when you do, please also include any exceptions you see in your log. If this isn't the same code, please make sure it's the same code.

Comment: What is written in the console when you start your web server? What server are you using?

Comment: Also, crank up the volume on that logger. I recommend TRACE or ALL when debugging these kinds of problems, as the frameworks tend to use DEBUG, TRACE instead of INFO. This will tell you what the framework is doing with your web.xml and mvc-dispatcher.xml

Comment: Ok, this might be a dumb question, but do you need to include the bean definition for UserService in your mvc-dispatcher.xml?  I see the `@autoWired` annotation, so I'm not sure if that overrides the need to explicitly define your bean... What about the `@Controller` annotation on the class? Do you need that?

Comment: This the code I'm using. The @Controller annotation must be there. As I said before I get : HTTP Status 404 - /guard_weblayer/

type Status report

message /guard_weblayer/

description The requested resource (/guard_weblayer/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.25

Comment: You have mapped your `mvc-dispatcher` to two different `<servlet-class>` - `DispatcherServlet` and `ResourceServlet`.

Comment: You're mapping the dispatcher servlet to "/", which matches almost nothing.

Comment: I have an example with spring security and it's working fine with mapping to "/". And I put resourceservlet mapping after hand to see if it helps and can get it wotk. But nothing is helping. I'm realy tired of it and can get any help anywhere.

Comment: It's working in other with mapping to "/" in other project I have so it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start over and use an example from [springbyexample](http://springbyexample.org/). It contains everything you need in a understandable fashion (and its in maven as well.)

Most likely that's easier than debugging the current code.

Comment: I want to know what can cause the problems and why it dosent work.I have an example: maven with spring security and it works but when i make new project and follow the same principles it dosent work,WHY? Am I missing something important? ??????? or what????